# Configuration of Volttron Central Platform to a Volttron Central instance on a remote server

Tags: volttron

I've got this configuration

```
{
    
    "volttron-central-address": "https://MYURL:8443",

    "volttron-central-serverkey": "MY KEY",
    "volttron-central-reconnect-interval": 5,
    "instance-name": "MYNAME",
    "stats-publish-interval": 30,
}
```

Then ran

```
python3 scripts/install-agent.py -s services/core/VolttronCentralPlatform -c config/vcp.config --tag vcp
vctl start --tag vcp
```

And I get the errors:

[image]

I suspect my tcp in .voltrron/config is not correct

```
[volttron]
message-bus = zmq
instance-name = Volttron-Tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config should include a vip-address in it.

```
[volttron]
vip-address = tcp://externalip:22916
```